# Loop over array with xml-values

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

So I have an array, which consists of xml-values. I want to check a node from each array entry. I've tried reaching xml-values as such:

```
var eventArtists:XML;
for each (xmlEvent in arEvents)
{
    if(xmlEvent.id == artistEvent.id)
    {
    boolExists = true;
    break;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, it seems it doesn't reach the xml-valus...

Here's a screenshot of my array:
[image]

Comment: You need to access the nodes in their own namespace http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Accessing_XML_attributes_and_nodes_with_different-16316.html

Answer (score 0):

try using `XMLList` or `Vector.<XML>` depending on the source of your array data